# Tomcat context's docBase won't work in gradle gretty

Tags: java, gradle, gretty

I use the virtual directory to serve the static resource uploaded by user. So I don't need to backup these files when redeploying the app.

```html
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"> 
  <Context path="/upload" docBase="/Users/junyu/Web/upload/"/> 
</Host>
```

I wrote these code into server/server.xml，and could be detected by gretty buildProduct task。Here is the output directory:
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzZz6.png)

Running output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed78V.png)

The upload context start successfully, but I couldn't access the pics in the docBase. 404 error.

Abandon the method using server.xml to config context.
Just config in the output/hello-web/server.json as following:

```js
"webApps": [
    { "contextPath": "/hello-web", "resourceBase": "webapps/hello-web.war" },
    { "contextPath": "/upload", "resourceBase": "/Users/junyu/Web/upload/" } 
]
```

The upload context will work, and pics in docBase could be accessed.

The question is server.json be newly produced in every build, and I have to change the server.json again. Is there a way to config once for all.

And, 'Web-app extra resource bases' just copy the resources into the project, and won't change after the original resource files change.